# Pass client info thru web site to WCF Rest service

Tags: asp.net, wcf, rest, soa

I need to know the best approach to pass the client's information (identity, locale, etc) thru my ASP.NET website to my back-end WCF RESTful web services.  I'd like the solution to be portable (reusable) to other applications as this model is very typical in my organization.

Here's the scenario:

- The ASP.NET website runs on a web
  server that sits in our perimeter
  zone.
- The WCF service application runs on
  an app server behind the firewall on
  our internal network.
- The client (user) can be on our
  internal network or on the web when
  he/she browses to the website.
- The website calls the web service to
  request various information or to
  perform certain tasks.
- The web service needs the client's
  information in order to perform these
  operations.

Note: the website is using Forms Authentication and is NOT impersonating the user. So, passing the identity info or current culture info using WCF extensibility (behavior, inspectors, etc) only gives us the identity and culture of the web server and not the actual client.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Where do you authenticate client?

Comment: Forms Authentication via web service which validates the user's credentials against the back-end data store. If successful, I return a custom "user" object to the web app that contains the roles, etc. This could easily be translated into a "ticket" as Roy suggests below but I still need a way to pass that to the service as well as the other information about the client/user that I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a case for federated security.

Basically, when the user logs in you generate a session ticket. This can be a number or a string. This ticket contains encoded information about the user's identity and/or his roles, and an expiration timestamp.

You pass this session ticket to your REST calls, and the receiving server decodes the ticket to get the information he needs. If a ticket is invalid (not decryptable, outdated, or without the required rights), the server method rejects the operation and returns a 401 Unauthorized HTTP status.

To implement this, you can rely on Microsoft's implementation ([wsFederationHttpBinding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730908.aspx)) or roll your own, which ususally requires less effort.

One more note: to generate and authenticate the tickets, you may create another service which sits behind your 2nd firewall, or you may use an in-memory DLL... But make sure that generating a ticket is not easy to do in case the webserver gets compromised.

Comment: How do you pass the ticket? I don't want to track sessions behind my service so I'd rather the identity, etc. be passed with each call. And remember, there's other information like locale (culture, time zone, etc) that I need as well.

Comment: Put all of that encoded in the ticket. You pass the ticket to the REST service as a parameter.